# Elevatezoom not working in version 1.9.1.0

Tags: rwd-theme, rwd, zoom

Recently I have had the web developer to update my website from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1.0 and my product zoom (Elevatezoom / RWD Theme) stopped working. I also can't contact the web developer since he moved country.

Did anyone else also had this problem? If so, how do I fix it?

**EDIT: FIXED**

I looked inside some files **(/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js)** and realized that `image.elevateZoom();` was commented, so all I did was delete the comment, and runned it. it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked inside some files (/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js) and realized that image.elevateZoom(); was commented, so all I did was delete the comment, and runned it. it worked.